# Exceeding maximum length of field in elasticsearch - error in kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elk, kibana-7

Discover: The length of [message] field of [-CSnZmwB_xkQcDCOrP1V] doc of [prod_logs] index has exceeded [1000000] - maximum allowed to be analyzed for highlighting. This maximum can be set by changing the [index.highlight.max_analyzed_offset] index level setting. For large texts, indexing with offsets or term vectors is recommended!

I get the above error in Kibana. I use ELK version 7.2.0. Answers / Suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: As the error message perfectly states you must adjust the setting 'index.highlight.max_analyzed_offset' of your index.

Please provide us your index settings via GET /prod_logs/_settings.

Answer (score 3):

You should change your mapping.If you can not update your mapping create a temp new index.And add **term_vector** your big text field

> "mappings": {
> "properties": {
> "sample_field": {
> "type": "text",
> **"term_vector": "**with_positions_offsets**"**
> }
> }
> }

Then clone your data to new index.

> POST /_reindex
> {
> "source": {
> "index": "old_index"
> },
> "dest": {
> "index": "new_index"
> }
> }

Then use "unified" in highlight query.

> "highlight": {
> "fields": {
> "textString": {
> **"type": "unified"**
> }
> }

like that.